# Sum Values in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following values in this format in a file:

## Filevalue.txt

abc
123
dev
456
hij
567
123
542

I need to add the numerical values from the character values which are below it

## Output

abc 123
dev 456
hij 1232

Anyhelp will be deeply appreciated?

Comment: Please show the what you have written so far, so that we can see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `awk` that mantains the order.

**Example**

```
$ awk '/[0-9]+/{a+=$1;next}a{print a;a=0}{printf($1FS);a=0}END{print a}' file
abc 123
dev 456
hij 1232
```

**Explanation**

`/[0-9]+/{a+=$1;next}`:When a **number** is *detected* as the content of the record,  it's value is accumulated into `a` var, then `next` is used to stop further processing and pass the flow to the *next* record.

`a{print a;a=0}`: **ONLY** when the counter is not null we print `a` value that correspond to the previous *word* and initialize it.

`{printf($1FS);a=0}`: Print current record and the separator avoiding the carriage return. This is applied to all text records.

`END{print a}`: Show the final counter that will remain after the last record.

Comment: Even without arrays! Nice!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this by using [`awk` and arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays.html):

```
$ awk '{if($1!~/^[0-9]+$/){cur=$1}else{sums[cur]+=$1}}END{for(el in sums){printf("%s %d\n",el,sums[el])}}' Filevalue.txt 
hij 1232
dev 456
abc 123
```

Here is the same code but written to the file `sum.awk` and with comments:

```
# this block will be executed for every line in the file
{
    # if current processing line is not a number, then it's a name of the next
    # group, let's save it to cur variable
    if ($1 !~ /^[0-9]+$/) {
        cur = $1
    } else {
        # here we're summing values
        sums[cur] += $1
    }
}
# this block will be executed at the end of file processing, here we're
# printing array with sums
END {
    for (el in sums) {
        printf("%s %d\n", el, sums[el])
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$ awk -f sum.awk Filevalue.txt 
hij 1232
dev 456
abc 123
```

The only downside of using awk here is that it doesn't preserve keys order.